# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Are these the same 10 questions that all reviewers see or different for each reviewer?

Comment: @generalnetworkerror, [the questions are the same for every reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174791/160519); unless the questions selected for review were asked by the reviewer, then they are omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can adding VLANs to a VPC be done hot?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/can-adding-vlans-to-a-vpc-be-done-hot)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why only port 80 for web services?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/why-only-port-80-for-web-services)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Netflow / Sflow tool](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/netflow-sflow-tool)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Portforwarding by Subdomain](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/portforwarding-by-subdomain)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Flow Control: to be or not to be?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/flow-control-to-be-or-not-to-be)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [What happens when the ARP cache overflows?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2327/what-happens-when-the-arp-cache-overflows)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Cause of high CPU load on Juniper peering router's routing engine](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/how-to-find-the-cause-of-high-cpu-load-on-a-juniper-peering-routers-routing-eng)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Juniper EX - disable multiple interfaces at the same time as a once off](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/juniper-ex-disable-multiple-interfaces-at-the-same-time-as-a-once-off)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Automating Cisco IOS Config Backups using Plink](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2196/automating-cisco-ios-config-backups-using-plink)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Wireless Access Point and Proxy Server Setup](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/wireless-access-point-and-proxy-server-setup)

  **Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 7)